# Truncate php variable before symbol

Tags: php, truncate, substr

Can anyone help me with a quick solution to a problem?

I have a string that is returned from an api, the string comes like this:

$year = "181?make=2008"

So I was using substr($year, 0,3); to get the first 3 digits out. I.E. 181
The problem is, now some of the strings are coming back with only 2 digits before the ?
Like this $year = "54?make=2008"

So, if I dont know how many digits will be coming before the ?, but I know that it will always end with a ? is there a way I can extract all data before the ? and turn that into a new variable...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: ...or use `strpos` along with `substr`.  Or one of 5 other string functions.

Comment: looks like a query string. you could probably use parse_url/parse_str to decompose it into components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$year = strstr("181?make=2008","?");
```

Answer (score 1):

list($data, $junk) = explode("?",$year);
$data would hold everything before the '?' then, you could also do some regex I imagine, but to me this is much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Regex would work to get the first part. Something like

```
preg_match("^([0-9]+)\?",$string,$match)
```

If it is the year you want, you can use

```
$year = substr("181?make=2008",-4)
```